Fourier transform of the Gaussian action for the real scalar bosonic field
In my current homework, we have to get familiar with quadratic theory in order to reach $\phi^4$-theory. So the starting point is
$$Z = \int Dx e^{-S[\phi]}$$
with the action for the real scalar bosonic field $\phi$
$$S[\phi] = \frac{1}{2} \int d^dx [(\partial \phi)^2 + r \phi^2 + g \phi^4].$$
The "Gaussian" action of this is given by $S_0[\phi] =S[\phi](g=0)$ and the propagator for this theory reads
$$G_0( x_1 ,x_2) = \langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle_0.$$
Now, the way we should go about this is first finding the momentum representation of $S_0[\phi]$ using the discrete Fourier transform
$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega}} \sum_k e^{-ikx} \phi_k.$$
Unfortunately this is already the point where I get problems. My general approach was to compute the two terms in the integrand by inserting the transform, using $\int d^dx \rightarrow \int \frac{d^dk}{(2 \pi)^d}$ and see where it leads me. Evaluating the square of the field, I find
$$\phi^2 = \frac{1}{\Omega} \sum_{k,k'} e^{-i(k+k')x} \phi_k \phi_{k'}$$
but now I can't even evaluate this any further. The known formula $$\frac{1}{N} \sum_i e^{i(k-k')x_i} = \delta_{k,k'}$$ can't be applied here. So my next thought was to do partial integration of the first term that seems to conventionally given by $(\partial \phi)^2 = \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$ (when studying I was genuinely confused by this because the definition of the $\partial$ given by Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-gradient) seems to indicate $(\partial \phi)^2 = \partial^\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$) and then transform the integral variable. If I understand the notation correctly, this should be
$$S_0[\phi] = - \frac{1}{2} \int d^dx [\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi] \cdot \phi$$
Using the momentum representation in position space $ik = \nabla$ I think one can extend this to the vector notation but I haven't found anything on that so far. The last step would then be to transform the field into momentum space but as above I'm not entirely sure how.
As you may see, I'm struggling with some of these steps, if anyone could help me clear my misunderstandings and point me in the right direction I'd be extremely grateful.
EDIT 1: As pointed out in the comments, I forgot to add some necessary information. $\Omega$ is the volume of the system. About the boundary conditions, they're actually not specified in the task, so I'm not entirely sure if one can just say if they vanish or are periodic, I'll come back to this in a moment in my second attempt.
Furthermore, since there is the $\partial$ operator, as known from 4-vector notation, this should now be extended to $d$ spatial dimensions, which makes $k$ also such a vector in momentum space.
So here's my attempt: My first step is to perform partial integration, leading to
$$S_0[\phi] = - \frac{1}{2} \int d^dx ([\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi] \cdot \phi - r \phi^2)$$
Note that for the boundary condition, I think that if one chooses vanishing ones, both terms in the first term of partial integration give 0, and if they're periodic, they're the same at both boundaries, thus cancelling each other. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Now I use the Kronecker Delta which has confused me before, leading to $\phi^2 = \phi_k \phi_{-k}. Now we have to evaluate the second derivative of $\phi$, i.e.
$$[\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi] \cdot \phi = - k^2 \phi_k \phi_{-k}$$
What did I use here? Just the normal definitions of the co- and contravariant derivatives one can find on Wikipedia. Plugging this into the Gaussian action and changing integration variables, I find:
$$S_0[\phi] = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d^dk}{(2 \pi)^d} \phi_k (k^2 + r) \phi_{-k}$$
Just to be sure again, the Kronecker Delta in the sum, does that mean whenever there's such an $e^{i(k+k')x}$ in a sum over either x, k or k', it always turns into a $\delta_{k,k'}$?
EDIT 2: My bad, I just realized I misunderstood the appearance of the Kronecker Delta which arises from the integration variable, which leads to the sum over k. I missed the comment.
Hence we have
$$S_0[\phi] = \frac{1}{2} sum_{k,k'} \int d^dx e^{-i(k+k')x} \phi_k (k^2 + r) \phi_{-k} = \frac{1}{2} \int \sum_k \phi_k (k^2 + r) \phi_{-k}$$
which is what the answer by @lcv says. Excuse my mistakes, it's been a long day.

What makes you think that the formula $\frac{1}{N} \sum_i e^{i(k-k')x_i} = \delta_{k,k'}$ can't be applied here?

Isn't it because we have no sum over i here? Just the sum over k and k'.

What makes you think that there isn't a sum over $x$ (i.e. $d^dx$, or in the discretized format sum over $x_i$)?

Why do you use a discrete Fourier transform and not the Fourier integral?

Are you quantizing in a (spatial) box? If yes, why? What are your boundary conditions? Periodic? What is $\Omega$? In this case you should clearly distinguish between spatial coordinates and time coordinate.  Likewise it is not clear what you mean by $k$. Is it a 4-vector or a 3-vector? Please clarify all these points in your question.

I will add the necessary information, a mistake on my behalf, sorry. To briefly answer some, $\Omega$ is the volume of what seems to be the box since on the exercise sheet the discrete FT is explicitly stated. For $k$, since $x$ is a vector with one temporal and d spatial coordinates, the same should hold for it. I mean the partial operator is the one used in 4-vectors, right?

As stated in the comments, there is indeed a delta function of momentum lurking here.
One possible source of confusion you have is that you wrote a discrete Fourier transform. The precise form of which  Fourier transform to use depends on the boundary conditions. The discrete Fourier transform you use arises if your system is in a box of sides $L_j$ (along axis $j$) and you use, for example, periodic boundary conditions.
If your system is infinitely extended, that is space is $\mathbb{R}^d$, you should use the standard, continuous Fourier transform.
So the BC tells you which Fourier transform to use and defines what is the space where the conjugate variable $k$ lives.
In any case, there will always be an identity like
$$
\int_\Omega \frac{dx^d}{|\Omega|} e^{ix(k-q)} =\delta_{k,q}.
$$
Here I'm using your notation and $\Omega$ is the box and $|\Omega|$ its volume.
The other possible source of confusion you have is that you will seem to be getting $\delta_{k,-k`}$ with a minus sign. But this is perfectly legitimate. Its origin is due to the fact that your fields are real.
So the end result should be something like
$$
\sum_k \phi_k ( \ldots ) \phi_{-k}. 
$$
I'm writing the result for the case of discrete $k$. Can you guess now what goes in the dots?

I redid my calculations with the help from all commenters and I think the answer is $(...) = (k^2 + r)/2$. I will edit the question where I add the necessary information and present my attempt at the solution.
